# Error creating bean with name 'refreshEventListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

When trying to start a RabbitMQ queue i'm getting an error message like the following:
Error creating bean with name 'refreshEventListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)

I've already seen some other questions similar to this one, where i could "solve" the error just by stopping my RabbitMQ docker container, in fact, i didn't get the error message when doing it, but i would need to make them both work together. It seems like there's some "conflict" between this queue and tomcat, i don't know exactly what, since i have many other queues working with the container docker.

Comment: It would be great to see some simple Spring Boot project from you to let us to reproduce and play with.

Comment: You need to specify software versions and show bean configuration - specifically `refreshEventListener`. And show the full stack trace.